# related field should populate with multiple fields - Odoo

Tags: python, module, orm, field, odoo

OpenERP: in a model i had a single column for Address, now i want to make it *related field* which should copy values of *street, street2, state_id, zip and city* columns in single Address field from res.partner (already had a field of Many2one type which selecting normally from contacts (res.partner)). when user select from Many2one this will copy another all address fields into my single field which is Address.  can i do it with (related="store_id.street"+"store_id.street2" ... )? or how it can be achieved?

```
> class Stores(models.Model):

    _name = 'tests.stores'

    _rec_name = 'name'

    _description = "Tests Stores"



    store_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Select Store", domain="[['category_id.name','ilike','store%']]")

    name = fields.Char(related='store_id.name', store=True, invisible="1")

    address = fields.Text(string="Address")

    is_exist = fields.Boolean(string="Still Exist?", default=True)

    owner_name = fields.Char(string="Owner Name")

    owner_image = fields.Binary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use onchange fuction.

```html
@api.onchange('store_id')
def change_address(self):
  self.address = self.store_id.street+self.store_id.street2
```

Comment: thanks for help. btw here is just a spelling mistake onchage... works fine :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that.I fixed it.XD

Comment: it seems not working in Odoo 14, is it deprecated method for ver 14? if yes, please help to have a working solution for ver. 14.

Comment: Why do you mark the answer as correct, if it is not working?

Comment: @Oralover. You mean it is working in v12 but not working in v14?

Comment: it is working now, don't know why the onchange function was not working even i hard coded values but it was not display any value. today, i have started my odoo 14 related VM, cleared browsing data & cache, and checked again, it is working fine now... it was happened once and someone helped me in odoo forum but my bad luck, i totally forgot. thanks to all friends here and there. ( also i have deleted my comment ). just can't add spaces in between if and where i want, can you guide me?

Comment: @Oralover .Try this self.address = self.store_id.street + "  " + self.store_id.street2